# Google map - Remove grid from ROADMAP

Tags: google-maps

I'm integrating the google map in my site. It works fine. However, it shows grid like this:
[image]

Which I want to remove it to make the map more good looking. Anyone has an idea how to remove this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a css problem (css being applied to the tiles which is modifying the appearance).  You need to fix that.

These rules are being applied to the tiles:

```
-webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px #AAA;
box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px #AAA;
```

From: #body .left .content img in style.css line 224

Remove them or override them on the map.

Comment: I have no idea how to figure that since I just call the script function from google library.

Comment: We can't help you then unless you provide a link to a live version (either your real map or an example that exhibits the problem).

Comment: `http://panhareach.com/index.php?page=location`   is the address of that page. Thanks