# Google Map not showing smooth lines between map grid squares

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have a question that may be somewhat strange. I have implemented Google Maps on different parts of my website, but in one part the map canvas is not showing smooth imaging. It is showing the distinctive grid squares. I have double checked the map api reference and it seems to be the right code. I have also checked against other parts of my site and the code is almost identical.

Here is the code I have for the offending grid lines map (googlemap.js)

```
var scriptTag = '<' + 'script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3&amp;key={my-key}&amp;sensor=false">'+'<'+'/script>';
document.write(scriptTag);
var latlng = '0';
var imagename = '';
var GPSLatitude = '48.2099177267394';
var GPSLongitude = '16.37563705444336';

window.setTimeout('initGmaps();',1000);

function initGmaps()
{
    var myOptions = {
    zoom:4,
    center:new google.maps.LatLng(GPSLatitude,GPSLongitude),
};
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(GPSLatitude,GPSLongitude)
});
function placeMarker(location)
{
    if (marker)
    {
        marker.setPosition(location);
    }
    else
    {
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: location,
        map: map
        });
    }
}
// google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize); <-- if I leave this in, it doesn't load the map for some strange reason
```

Here is where I call the map (functions.php <-- this sends the co-ords to the map)

```
$google_map = "
      <script type='text/javascript' src='googlemap.js'></script>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
          GPSLatitude = '$GPSLatitude';
          GPSLongitude = '$GPSLongitude';
          imagename = '$image_name';
        </script>
     ";
```

Here are a couple of screenshots of the issue

Distinctive Grid Lines

[image: Distinctive Grid Lines]

Smooth Image

[image: No Grid Lines]

Just not quite sure where I am going wrong with this. Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: You have css rules that apply to the tiles (img tags) that are being applied to the map.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google maps grid lines appearing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20522471/google-maps-grid-lines-appearing/20524645#20524645)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I remove grid lines from Google Map (v3)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18945991/can-i-remove-grid-lines-from-google-map-v3/18948036#18948036)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google map - Remove grid from ROADMAP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11397343/google-map-remove-grid-from-roadmap/11397811#11397811)

Comment: Thanks @geocodezip Do you think you could add it as an answer so I can mark it as the correct answer. CSS styling didn't even cross my mind :/ Rookie mistake :)

Comment: It is a duplicate.  Vote for the best duplicate.